# Way to filter R unit tests by context in testthat?

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I have a suite of unit tests in R spread out across numerous files. These tests all run just fine via the 'testthat' package.
However, I cannot seem to find a way to filter tests run by the package's 'context' name. For example, if I have tests spread across different files that all fall under a context with the name "Integration," how can I get R to only run those?

I am aware of the 'filter' argument in the test() function that allows you to filter by test file name, but I am looking to filter by context in this case. I was not able to find anything related to such functionality in the documentation, so any help would be appreciated!

Link to package -> https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/testthat/testthat.pdf